# Are different types of initialization derivatives of other types, or are they separate completely?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading about initialization [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) and it talks about different types of initialization, as demonstrated, where `a` is an arbitrary variable (with various different syntax for each):

- Default initialization `T`
- Value initialization `T{}`
- Direct initialization `T(a)`
- Copy initialization `T val = a`
- List initialization `T{...}`
- Aggregate initialization `T{...}`
- Reference initialization `T &ref = a`
- Zero initialization `T{}`
- Constant initialization `static T &ref = a`

A copy constructor may be used by copy initialization but copy initialization is not the same as a copy constructor. (Right?) This made me wonder about the following:

The syntax for certain types of initialization overlap, for example value initialization and zero initialization both use similar syntax, aggregate initialization and list initialization have similar syntax, etc.

**Question:** Does this mean that certain types of initialization are derivatives from others? E.g. is zero initialization derived from value initialization when specific circumstances are met and is aggregate initialization a form of list initialization as these all have similar syntax.

If not then what is the priority and ordering in which initialization type occurs?

Comment: On that page, the examples are just examples, not exhaustive cases. Yes, aggregate initialization is a subset of list initialization; and the behaviour of `T{}` depends on what `T` is.  You can find full detail by reading the section titled "Initializers" in the C++ Standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the order of your categories:

1. Value initialization causes some types (including the primitive types like `int`) to have a *value*, unlike default initialization which leaves them uninitialized.  It is possible to make a class type have this behavior, which can be very efficient (if confusing to someone who assumes that the default constructor tells the whole story).
2. Direct vs. copy initialization as concepts are actually orthogonal to list initialization, which can be either type.  (The technical terms *direct initialization* and *copy initialization* exclude the list-initialization cases.)
3. Copy initialization typically does involve a copy (or move) constructor for a class type.  However, the implementation often optimizes it away, and in C++17 the constructor call [often doesn't happen even in principle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).
4. List initialization just performs aggregate initialization for aggregates (except for certain special cases involving single-element lists introduced in C++14).
5. Aggregate initialization and zero initialization are effects, not syntaxes (although the site gives the special case of `char foo[2]="";` since it's not covered by the usual list-initialization rule).
6. Reference initialization is just "what happens when the variable is a reference and it's not list initialization".  It includes special rules for converting the initializer to an object to which the reference can bind.
7. Constant initialization is scheduling, not semantics: it says that certain variables get initialized earlier than others (which matters when the others might use them).

Answer (score 0):

> A copy constructor may be used by copy initialization but copy initialization is not the same as a copy constructor. (Right?)

This is analogous to "A function may be used in a function call, but function is not the same as a function call. (Right?)". Indeed, they are separate, but related concepts.

> Question: Does this mean that certain types of initialization are derivatives from others?

It is unclear what you mean by "derivatives from others". Sure, in certain value initialization cases, zero initialization is performed. But zero initialization is not performed in all value initialization (for example, when a class has user defined constructor). Furthermore, there are situations where zero initialization is performed where value initialization is not (for example, variables of static storage duration are zero initialized before any other initialization (if any).

The site that you linked has fairly detailed description of situations where each of the possible initializations are performed. The authoritative description can be found in the C++ standard document.